# How disable other connection's .if wifi available

Tags: android, android-internet

Is there any solution to disable all connection's(i.e mobile)

if `WIFI` available.

Comment: It is controlled automatically by the framework (i.e. WiFi is always set as default connection if available). So you dont need to worry about it.

Comment: i want to use one connection at a time only .i want to disable Mobile GSM .if wifi is there

Comment: on my device (SGIII) it is done automatically by Android, you don't have to do anything.

Comment: mobile connection will be disabled automatically if your phone is connected to WiFi

Comment: waqas are you sure..couse i ll have to fix that isssue

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. You can verify this on your device too :)

Comment: can u check this question "How to disable Mobile Data on Android".what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager)  
getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if (mWifi.isConnected())
{
  turnData(false);
}
void turnData(boolean ON) throws Exception
{

if(bv == Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
{

Log.i("version:", "Found Froyo");
try{ 
    Method dataConnSwitchmethod;
    Class telephonyManagerClass;
    Object ITelephonyStub;
    Class ITelephonyClass;
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    telephonyManagerClass = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
Method getITelephonyMethod = telephonyManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
getITelephonyMethod.setAccessible(true);
ITelephonyStub = getITelephonyMethod.invoke(telephonyManager);
ITelephonyClass = Class.forName(ITelephonyStub.getClass().getName());

if (ON) {
     dataConnSwitchmethod = ITelephonyClass.getDeclaredMethod("enableDataConnectivity"); 

} else {
    dataConnSwitchmethod =  ITelephonyClass.getDeclaredMethod("disableDataConnectivity");
}
dataConnSwitchmethod.setAccessible(true);
dataConnSwitchmethod.invoke(ITelephonyStub);
}catch(Exception e){
       Log.e("Error:",e.toString());
  }
else
 {
Log.i("version:", "Found Gingerbread+");
 final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
 final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
 iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
 final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
 final Class iConnectivityManagerClass =   Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
 final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
 setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
 setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, ON);
  }
 }
```

Don't forget to add these permissions in the manifest file;

```
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS
android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
```